# Calculating length between 2 points on a curve in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to display the length of the individual segments of a spline to the user. The spline can be BEZIER, NURBS or POLY. I am able to get the full length of these curves using calc_length method.

For POLY, i figured that it must be the vector length between the control points. But for NURBS and BEZIER, is there a way to calculate the length between each of the set of control points in Python?